# Ruby 1.92 and Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion and had to install Xcode 4.4 (4.1 would not work). I believe this adversely affected my Ruby install, and more specifically Sass.

When I type `$ sass --version` I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in 'report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem sass (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in 'activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in 'gem'
    from /usr/bin/sass:18
```

Any ideas? I am running ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421)

Comment: You say you're running 1.9.2 but the directories indicate Ruby 1.8.

Comment: I know, that's part of the problem. I'm confused. If I type `$ ruby --version` it tells me "1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421)"

Comment: The `ruby` binary probably isn't the problem, it's the `sass` binary, and possibly your `$PATH`.

Comment: @AlistairIsrael Yes, I am using RVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

And then I did:

```
$ gem install sass --pre
```

And that worked. When I do `$ sass -v` it reports `Sass 3.2.0.alpha.275`and not the error message above.